# How to copy a file two folders back by replacing file name with names of folders using python

Tags: python, operating-system, copy, rename, shutil

I have several folders such as `a1-b1, a1-b2, a1-b3. a2-b2` and so on. Within each folder there are subfolders e.g. `c_1, c_2, c_3` and so on. Within each subfolder I have data files with same name e.g. `abc.dat`. I desire to copy `abc.dat` two folders back by replacing its name with subfolders e.g. `a1-b1-c_1.dat, a1-b1-c_2.dat, a1-b3_c1.dat` etc..

My present approach can only copy one folder back, but also changes the name of `abc.dat` files in their existing directories, which I would now like to avoid and prefer that these files are copied with their desired changed names in two folders back, but exist as `abc.dat` in their current directories. Thanks in advance for your support!

```
input_dir = "/user/my_data"
# Walk through all files in the directory that contains the files to copy
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_dir):
    

    for filename in files:
        if filename == 'abc.dat':
            base = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(root))
            #Get current name
            old_name = os.path.join(base, filename)
            #Get parent folder
            parent_folder = os.path.basename(base)
            #New name based on parent folder
            new_file_name = parent_folder + ".dat" #assuming same extension
            new_abs_name = os.path.join(base, new_file_name) 
            #Rename to new name
            os.rename(old_name,new_abs_name)
            #Copy to one level up
            one_level_up = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(base, os.pardir))
            one_level_up_name = os.path.join(one_level_up, new_file_name)
            shutil.copy(new_abs_name,one_level_up_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured out its solution. Here it is!

```
import os
import shutil
current_dir = os.getcwd()
for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(current_dir):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.dat'):
            folder_1 = os.path.split(os.path.split(dirpath)[0])[1]
            folder_2 = os.path.split(os.path.split(dirpath)[1])[1]
            os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, f), 
                      os.path.join(dirpath, folder_1 + '-' + folder_2 + '.dat')) 
            totalCopyPath = os.path.join(dirpath, folder_1 + '-' + folder_2 + '.dat') 
            shutil.copy(totalCopyPath,current_dir)
```